# Executing a SSIS package from stored procedure is timing out

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, timeout

I have a conundrum and I'm stumped and hoping y'all can help.

Here is my scenario: I am loading data into our database through a web interface. First, I upload the file to the SQL box, then I call the script which extracts and loads the data into SQL.

I recently changed this process so that now, instead of executing the package from within the web application, I am calling a stored procedure to execute the script.

Here is the core of my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExecuteSsisPackage]
@Package NVARCHAR(100),
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @executionID BIGINT
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.create_execution
    @folder_name = 'Imports', -- nvarchar(128)
    @project_name = 'DataImports, -- nvarchar(128)
    @package_name = @Package, -- nvarchar(260)
    @use32bitruntime = 1, -- bit
    @execution_id = @executionID OUTPUT -- bigint
SELECT @executionId

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @executionId, 50, N'SYNCHRONIZED', @parameter_value = 1 -- turn on synchronization
EXEC ssisdb.catalog.start_execution @executionID;
RETURN (@executionID)
END
```

Here is the odd part: when I run the stored procedure from management studio it executes fine. However, when I execute this from the web application it times out. But, if I turn OFF synchronization it executes just fine through the web app. The problem with disabling synchronization is that I need to pull some summary info off the data after it has been loaded.

I've even tried rolling my own 'synchronization' from a post I found:

```
DECLARE @status AS BIGINT = 1;
WHILE(@status = 1 OR @status = 2 OR @status = 5 OR @status= 8)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Status: ' + CAST(@status AS VARCHAR(10))
    PRINT 'waiting 2 seconds for Package to finish'
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:2';

    SET @status = (SELECT [Status] FROM SSISDB.[catalog].[executions]
            WHERE execution_id = @executionID);
END

PRINT 'Exit Status: ' + CAST(@status AS VARCHAR(10))
```

This also times out. I did some digging and found that when the SP is executing from the web (but not management studio) there is a lock: LCK_M_S and the wait_resource is: KEY: 9:72057594041532416 (d28bcaafb8df). Again, this only occurs when executing the SP from the web app.

Some more digging unearthed the culprit for the lock. It is the PK_Operations key of the SSISDB.internal.operations table. This is the conundrum. Any ideas why this occurs only through the web and when synchronized it turned on??

Comment: If you gin up a Hello World equivalent package, do you experience the same behaviour? What is logged in the SSISDB while the package is running? Do you see any difference in the log messages when it runs via web versus you? What account is the website executing the package as? If you launch SSMS as the same user via `RUNAS`, can you recreate the issue? 2012 or 2014? How is the server on patch levels [Reference chart](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)

Comment: 1. I've tried a variety of similar packages and the same occurs for them so it isn't package specific.

Comment: 2. Error: 
The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

and

DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Source" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: 3. The web fails when 'run synchronized' is true. It succeeds from the web when it is set to false. It succeeds, regardless, when run in Management Studio. No difference that I can see when it succeeds via the web or via MS.

Comment: 4. App Pool identity: I am running it as the default IIS APPPOOL\ identity but it has necessary permissions. I've tried changing the account the app pool is using to my own and the same behavior occurs.

Comment: 5. Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: I don't understand how the supplied code can have `@use32bitruntime = 1` and raise `The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered...run the package in 32-bit mode`

Comment: Yes, seems odd to me as well. I've chased it down inside the SSISDB to see if I could find a possible bug but the @use32BitRuntime parameter is passed to the ssisdb.internal.start_execution_internal which calls a CLR method.